# Can we Develop the website as well with react Native ? is their any way to do it?

Tags: react-native

I Am new to react and React native but can any one let me know that i can develop
website, App (Android, IOS) from same platform (REACT NATIVE)

I Am asking here because on official site of React Native
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

they have shown the picture of Mobile, i-pad, And Desktop View as well
so may be there is chance we can develop it in all platform

Thanks in Advance

Comment: From the 1st paragraph on the official React Native website:
*You can use React Native today in your existing Android and iOS projects or you can create a whole new app from scratch.*
2nd paragraph:
*With React Native, one team can maintain two platforms and share a common technology—React.*

**Yes.** If you're asking, since it's unclear from your question, if you can develop a plain website in React native, you can use libraries such as [this one](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/examples/).

Answer (score 0):

Web based apps (that load on site pages, in browser) can be built with React JS:
https://reactjs.org

React Native is an entire platform allowing you to build native, cross-platform mobile apps, and React.js is a JavaScript library you use for constructing a high performing UI layer. 
React.js is the heart of React Native, and it embodies all React’s principles and syntax, so the learning curve is easy.

React-Native doesn’t use HTML & CSS to render the app, but provides alternative components that work in a similar way.

Comment: There are packages which allow React Native to be transpiled to React DOM, enabling it to create web apps in RN as well.